# RootController subview won't display full screen

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a custom splash screen that is built and updated during runtime.  We have a RootController that we add a subview to.  This subview contains a UIImageView and Label.  Both the UIImageView and it's parent are set to scale and are set to 1024x768.  The issue is that the subview and image appear to be displayed as 768x1024 so the bottom of the image is cut off and the width of the subview doesn't take up the entire screen.

The gist of our code is below

```
window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
viewController = new RootViewController ();
window.RootViewController = viewController;
window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

Then during the transition, we use a public property pointing to the root controller to add the subview containing the image etc...

```
RootViewController.View.AddSubview(controllers[view].View);
```

The black box just covers some info I don't want shown to the world.  The grey area is the part of the root controller view that isn't being covered by the subview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  For whatever reason, the following statement was causing my problem.  controllers[view].View.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0,0,1024,768); which is called before the AddSubview statement.  No clue why this is happening.